# How to count running threads from my thread-class in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've implemented that thread-class in Java.

It's instances do some business in my mysql-database on the same table.
When all threads have finished, I want to call an other method, to read the table.
That means, the last running thread-instance has to call the "read-method". Therefore every thread needs to know, how many of it's "brothers and sisters" are still running, when it finishes.

That brings me to my question:
Is there a proper solution or Thread-method to count all the running thread-instances from same parent-class?

I hope I don't overlooked a easy solution for this.

Comment: Rather than "counting" your secondary threads, you should `join()` on each of the threads you create, which will cause the main thread to wait until they have all finished. Can you post your current code so we can see how the threads are being started?

Comment: Just call the `join` method on all your threads in turn.

Comment: Semaphores and count-down latches are your friend too. But if I were you, I'd really read up on multi-threading before jumping into the spiny world of synchronisation. It can save you **a lot** of pain.

Comment: Also you need to be sure that each thread releases its database related locks before being preempted, so that all other threads do not get starved.

Comment: thanks friends! i knew i heard of something like that: joins... :D
@CraigOtis There is not thread-code existing yet, but I wondered about it and now I've got the solution! thanks.

Comment: The duplicate question answers how to count all the threads which are instances of particular Thread-subclass. Nevertheless the whole approach is wrong. There are better mechanisms to solve your *original* problem.

Comment: @DavidWallace Jup. Thanks too!

Comment: @biziclop Yes, I have too. ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Wow, OK. I think I have to do a little more work here... :) Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

In your `Thread` class make this variable:

```
private static int counterAlive = 0;
```

Each time you're creating a new one count it, when it's getting down uncount it.

Also add this:

```
public static int getAliveThreads(){
    return this.counterAlive;
}

public void run(){
   counterAlive++;
.
.
.
.

   counterAlive--;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that's a terrible idea. Have you tried it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when it's getting down"?

Comment: why is it terrible? i think it could work good... or why not?

Comment: when some thread is done his job, in the end of `run()`

Comment: So you'd have one thread that checks `counterAlive` over and over?

Comment: no, you're using it outside of your Thread class, so when all of your Threads are working, this counter is changed all the time

Comment: @NewOutlaw Why not? Because without synchronization all the threads could see a different value of the counter, in fact, the counter may not even be updated at all from the perspective of another thread. This is what the `CountDownLatch` class was created for.

Comment: He _could_ use an atomic integer counter, which _might_ work.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it does seem to be re-inventing a wheel.  This particular problem is _precisely_ what the `join` method is for.  Doing it any other way seems wrong to me.

Comment: @DavidWallace If it's at the end of a thread, `join()` is indeed the simplest solution. But in the real world you shouldn't create threads at all, you're much better off using executors, in which case `join()` doesn't work: in these cases latches and semaphores are the idiomatic solution.

Comment: This just gets worse and worse with every edit. Now a simple uncaught exception can guarantee that the counter will never reach zero. This is simply not the way to do it. As @TimBiegeleisen said, with an atomic integer and a great deal of care you can make this work but there are better and safer solutions.